# Sending payment using PayPal from my app's users

Tags: paypal

I would like to create an app where users would authorize my app with their PayPal account and then my app would be able to send payments to other PayPal users in their name without them having to do anything anymore (imagine background cron payments). I was looking at PayPal APIs but it seems that most APIs are meant to be used in a way that app is a receiver or sender of money, and not that app just coordinates sending or receiving money for its users, or that user has to be in a loop because protocol with redirect to PayPal for user's confirmation.

Is there a PayPal API for this?

Comment: If I understand this question correctly NO! It sounds like you are requesting a feature that would allow you to fully manage the users PayPal account, this is prohibited by design to protect the user from malicious use of this kind of power.

Comment: But it also prevents useful uses. Isn't user the one who should decide that?

Comment: That's really up to PayPal to decide, as suggest the adaptive payments system can be used to grant some control to the billing party within reasonable limits and can be used to simulate full control through the use of a third party account (Company PayPal account), however to receive full control you would have to unlimited transactions and limits.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're describing a third party [Mass Pay](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/mass-payments). Mass pay would take money from their PayPal account and send it to another account. For your part, you would need [third party authorization](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/third-party/) for each account they wanted to send from. This would require them to authorize your API username. MassPay doesn't require them to subscribe to anything (you pay when you use it).

Comment: It seems I can ask for a third party authorization through a program as well: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this api:

"Use the Pay API operation to transfer funds from a sender's PayPal account to one or more receivers' PayPal accounts"

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/

Example, Preapproved payment example:

"In this example, the sender has a valid preapproval agreement with you and makes a payment of $100 to a PayPal-registered receiver and $50 to another PayPal-registered receiver. The payment is completed without the sender logging in to paypal.com."

```
curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay \
  -s \
  --insecure \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: app_id" \
  -d actionType=PAY \
  -d cancelUrl=http://your_cancel_url \
  -d currencyCode=USD \
  -d feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER \
  -d memo=Preapproval-payment-example \
  -d preapprovalKey=PA-9JR04288NR0519129 \
  -d receiverList.receiver(0).amount=100.00 \
  -d receiverList.receiver(0).email=receiver1@domain \
  -d receiverList.receiver(0).primary=false \
  -d receiverList.receiver(1).amount=50.00 \
  -d receiverList.receiver(1).email=receiver2@domain/em> \
  -d receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false \
  -d requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US \
  -d returnUrl=http://your_return_url \
  -d reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError=true \
  -d senderEmail=sender@domain
```

Edited:
How to Set Up a Payment Preapproval Using Adaptive Payments,
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PayPay's Adaptive Payments API.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/

You can enable "Funds Transfer within a Group" and allow "person-to-person" payments. Pretty cool stuff.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/use-cases/uc_social-transfers-within-group/

Comment: I would probably also have to preaprove those payments? Do you have any examples for this? Or maybe existing open source libraries which provide this functionality?

Comment: You always have to pre-aprove the payments, however, the API gives you ability to set an agreement between the app and the user, for multiple payments. This way, you could set a maximum amount over a period of time, and the app will be authorized to do payments (send money) on the user's behalf. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/
Unfortunately I don't have any open source code to show you.